# SpringBoot check if injected Properties are set NotNull

Tags: spring-boot

I know I can easily inject a property file in SpringBoot 2.2 with the following construct

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class MyProps {

  @NonNull
  private final String neededProperty;
  @NonNull
  private final List<SampleProps> lstNeededProperty;

  public String getFirstSample(){
    return lstNeededProperty.get(0); //throws NPE
  }

}

@ConstructorBinding
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class SampleProps {
  String key;
  String label;
}
```

and yml file like:

```
expample:
  neededProperty: test1
  lstNeededProperty:
    -key: abc
     label: input
```

The `@NonNull` works quite well for the `String` but fails for the `List` - since the NPE is thrown even when the list will be set.

Is there a *simple* way to check if the `List` is initialized? I've tried `@Postconstruct` but this isn't called at all.

Comment: Maybe you replace Lombok and debug what comes into the constructor?

Comment: What looked like an useful approach fails. I think the major problem is that the `yml` file might be splitted into several pieces. Therefore it is initialised several times - which makes a check impossible due to several checks and the cummulation seems to be done internally later. A hook into when its done would be great to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for the size and intialize the list:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example")
public final class MyProps {

  @NonNull
  private final String neededProperty;
  @Size(min=1)
  private final List<String> lstNeededProperty = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Nope, won't help either :-/ Even with the initialized list the access throws a NPE later on.

Comment: So please post the Stacktrace and the code where the NPE happens

Comment: Plus your properties or yaml file and the constructor of MyProps

Comment: I've updated the sample to give a better pic from my setup. Using Lombok.

Comment: I created a working example for you: https://github.com/simasch/spring-boot-yaml Please check it out and compare it with your project

Comment: I'm confused cuz in your sample is pretty nothing included.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I forgot to push. Check it out now